# Purposely invalidate the html5 form validator using dummy pattern

Tags: html, reactjs, regex, validation

I want to programatically set the input to invalid if specific condition is met e.g

`<input type="text" required />`

Lets take a variable `isValid` an example, if that is `false`, i want that bubble to show up with default browser bubble (onsubmit) and the custom error thats provided. So to add custom errors i figured the solition

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    required 
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid name')"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')" 
/>
```

However this only check if its empty, the extra validation comes from a field called `pattern` however that regex, so I was thinking maybe do a pretty much all case regex when is 'isValid == true' else a regex that will fall everytime e.g. (react)

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    required
    pattern={isValid ? 'regex valid always' : 'regex fail always'}
    ...
/>
```

Could this even work? is there a better way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Well, it might work better if you write `pattern` instead of `patern`, but what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Regex fails always: `(?!)`

Comment: @revo and empty strings bring back always valid, thats all i needed, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @revo for his help got it working with just:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    required
    pattern={isValid ? null : '(?!)'}
    ...
/>
```